# C# Cannot find dll if it's installed with the program running

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, gac

I'm running a program in C# .Net, WPF, and having this problem: if I try to load a dll dynamically from the GAC and it's not presente, the system show an error, then I install the dll in the GAC and system still isn't able to find it. But, if just restart the system, whitout changing anything, it find's the DLL.

For more details, in an async thread, I call one dll dynamically from the GAC, and this dll calls another  DLLs dynamically, and are those "second" dlls that are causing this problem.

The dlls are being called using the following:

```
            var classType = Type.GetType(fullyQualifiedName, true);
            T assemblyClass = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
```

Also, the "fullyQualifiedName" follows the format:

`NameSpace.Class, AssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=number of the token, processorArchitecture=x86`

And the "assemblyClass" is cast to an interface.

Thanks in advance.